# Difference between redis and other databases like sql or mongodb in term of memory or storage?

Tags: redis

Redis is an in-memory database that persists on disk . What does it imply ? As per I know other databases also uses disk space for storage ? If not , where are other databases stored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis con persists on disk what he have on memory. All it's data is in memory and flushes it on the disk periodically. This mean that all your data must fit in memory. This is, depending on the case, a limit(limited space) or an opportunity(very fast).